# Azure Bicep - Role assignment - Principal does not exist in the directory

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I've created a Bicep template. In it I create a user-assigned identity and reference it in other resources like this

```
var identityName = 'mid-dd-test'
var roleName = 'TestRole'
var roleDescription = 'Some test'
var roleScopes = [
    resourceGroup().id
]
var resolvedActions = [
    'Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups/*'
  'Microsoft.Compute/sshPublicKeys/*'
]
var permittedDataActions = []

resource userId 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities@2018-11-30' = {
  name: identityName
  location: resourceGroup().location  
}

resource roleDef 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions@2018-01-01-preview' = {
  name: guid(subscription().id, 'bicep', 'dsadsd')  
  properties: {
    roleName: roleName
    description: roleDescription
    type: 'customRole'    
    assignableScopes: roleScopes
    permissions: [
      {        
        actions: resolvedActions
        dataActions: permittedDataActions
      }
    ]
  }
}

resource roles 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2018-09-01-preview' = {
  name: guid(subscription().id, 'bicep-roleassignments', 'dsddsd')  
  properties: {
    principalId: userId.properties.principalId
    roleDefinitionId: roleDef.id
  }
}
```

Whenever I deploy this I need 2 runs. The first run ends in the error message:

```
Principal XXX does not exist in the directory YYY
```

where `XXX` would be a principal id the user-assigned identity has and `YYY` is my tenant id. If I now look into the portal the identity is created and `XXX` is the correct id.

So when I now simply re-run the deployment **it works**.

I consider it a bug in `dependsOn` which should relate to ARM templates and not Bicep. I could not find any place where I can report ARM template issues to Microsoft.

I'm asking to assure that I do not miss something else here.

**Edit**: Added complete working sample which shows the bug. To use it, copy the script content into a `test.bicep` locally. Then create a resource group (lets call it "rg-test"), ensure that your local POSH context is set correctly and execute the following line in the folder where you stored the bicep in:

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -Name deploy -Mode Incremental -TemplateFile .\test.bicep -ResourceGroupName rg-test
```

Comment: are you trying to do role assignement ? how do you reference the newly created managed identity ?

Comment: @Thomas I will create an updated complete sample.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the role assignment, you need to specify the `principalType` to `ServicePrincipal` and also use an api version greater or equal than: `2018-09-01-preview`.

When you create a service principal, it is created in Azure AD. It takes some time for the service principal to be replicated globally. By setting the `principalType` to `ServicePrincipal`, it tells the ARM API to wait for the replication.

```bicep
resource roles 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2018-09-01-preview' = {
  name: guid(subscription().id, 'bicep-roleassignments', 'dsddsd')  
  properties: {
    principalId: userId.properties.principalId
    roleDefinitionId: roleDef.id
    principalType: 'ServicePrincipal'
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Should it not wait on other principal types too obviously? Seems like this should be the default behavior since it works on the second run.

Comment: you cant create user or group from arm template so it doesnt really matter for other types i guess.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference a newly created identity inside `identity` property of the target resource. `dependsOn` is redundant because bicep creates resources in the correct order based on actual usage:

```
resource userId 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities@2018-11-30' = {
  name: 'myidentity'
  location: resourceGroup().location
}

resource appService 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2021-02-01' = {
  name: 'appserviceName'
  location: resourceGroup().location
  properties: {
    //...
  }
  identity: {
    type: 'UserAssigned'
    userAssignedIdentities: {
      '/subscriptions/{your_subscription_id}/resourceGroups/${resourceGroup().name}/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/${userId.name}': {}
    }
  }  
}
```

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/resource-declaration?tabs=azure-powershell) doesn't recommend to use `dependsOn` without as strong reason:

> In most cases, you can use a symbolic name to imply the
> dependency between resources. If you find yourself setting explicit
> dependencies, you should consider if there's a way to remove it.

Comment: I will create a complete sample and update the question. I already use the `identity` in my dependend resource. As I wrote, the second run works which would'nt be the case if I missed this. It seems to be timing still.

Comment: That would be helpful. I run my example on azure but didn't reproduce

Comment: I added a working sample and some notes.

Answer (score 0):

So bicep does not require the `dependsOn` segment if referencing the property correctly.

Need to reference the `properties.principalId` of the userId in the resource block.

So would look like:

`userId.properties.principalId`

Here's a [quickstart that calls](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/modules/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/user-assigned-identity-role-assignment/1.0/main.bicep) out in a working example how this would work.

Comment: I know. I just wanted to ensure that the 2nd resource waits in case the implicit dependency is somehow ignored here.

Comment: If curious can validate by running a `bicep build` will output the ARM template and should expand the dependencies.